# I am getting page like this in angular Json editor library

Tags: angular12

Here the CSS styles are not applying i don't understand why.I have included
*@import '~jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.css'* this link in the src/styles.css but i am not getting the buttons.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ5TD.png)